# Entity Framework many to many relationship between 3 tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I had a scenario where an Organization Works in some cities of a state,In this situation I needed to relate `Organization` with `City` with a `many to many relationship`. I made a table with Composite key having `OrgainzationID` and `CityID`

**Organization , City**

- ID
- Name
- IsActive

**OrganizationCities**

- OrganizationID
- CityID

Everything is working fine using EF, EF hides this junction table and shows collections in the objects of Organization and City , At the end I associate an organization with a user and perform validations for modules and show related modules to users.

Now I need to `map Organization to States and then to Cities`. for example an organizations works in multiple states and in multiples cities of their respective states.

I did same for this scenario, created this table

**OrganizationStateCities**

- OrganizationID
- StateID
- CityID

Now instead of hiding this table EF shows this table EF shows it as a `collection` in `Organization Object`, and no `collections` are shown in `City` `Organization` or `State`.

Please help me out on this many to many relationship issue.

Comment: Why do you want to map `Organization` to `States` and then to `Cities`? Wouldn't it be easier to map `Cities` to `States` and keep the mapping between `Organization` and `Cities`? After all, a city can only be in one state but according to your `OrganizationStateCities` a city can be in two or more states which, IMHO is a design flaw.

Comment: hmmm . . . yes you are right @RePierre . but it's possible to have three tables joined like this ?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear enough to me... If you are referring to joining `Organizations`, `Cities` and `States` then, yes you can join them without any problem. However, in your EF model you won't have a direct link from `Organization` to `State`. `State` will be a navigation property of `City` objects.

Comment: hmmm so direct link is not possible . . . Thank you @RePierre